# Make [Azure-Arm] a synonym of [azure-resource-manager]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[azure-arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-arm) has 16 questions and is simply an acronym of [azure-resource-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-resource-manager) which has 293 questions. (at 16 of them its hardly a big task!) and hence should be made a synonym

Comment: @Kyll I knew I'd seen that document somewhere! but my foo was misplaced it seems. Would it be better to post this as a one or the other? or two separate posts? (I'm not entirely clear on the process - hence I'm here!)

Comment: As I see it there's not much point in burninating this tag. It seems to be perfectly fine on SO (non-ambiguous, on-topic, ...) but is just redundant of a bigger tag. I think synonymizing is the right action to take. To make sure that the community thinks so too, you'll need an upvoted answer in that sense.

Comment: @Kyll Good point, I've modified the question to just make it a synonym request

Comment: Since you have greater than 2500 rep and more than 5 score in the tag [azure-resource-manager], you should be able to suggest this synonym at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-resource-manager/synonyms